# loading multiple css, images and js file in CodeIgniter

Tags: css, codeigniter

I have a three different folders (css, js, images)placed where the system, application, user_guide folders live.. Now I am trying to include those files in my header_view.php like below:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url()?>/css/styles.css" type="text/css" media="screen">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url()?>/css/layout.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
```

Then in my view file I am including the header file like this

```
$this->load->view('header_view');
```

None of the css styles are showing..
Can someone please help me with this? thanks alot...

Comment: This calls for basic debugging first. 1. Go to your browser's "View source" view 2. Copy the generated URLs pointing to the style sheets 3. try to open them manually in the browser. What happens?

Answer (score 0):

The obvious answer is to look at the HTML source, and visit the `href` that's been output by CI. It'll be something like `http://mysite/com/css/styles.css`

Visit that URL; if the CSS loads, the problem is elsewhere. If the CSS file does not load, then it is in the wrong directory.

Your `.htaccess` may also be rewriting the CSS request.

Your rule may have to look something like:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

to prevent CSS files from being rewritten.

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like this to load them

```
<?php echo link_tag('css/reset.css'); ?>
<?php echo link_tag('css/main.css'); ?>
```

If your CSS files and media files are in the root like they should be, get rid of the first "/"

It should be

```
css/styles.css
```

Your css, media files and js files should live under "public_html"